# Materialize SideNav Mobile does not allow scroll even though there is more content

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I noticed that if the screen size of the mobile device is not big enough, it hides the rest of SideNav but scrolling down is not possible.

To replicate the problem, please go to my [personal website](https://yiikuochong.com), use the inspect tool to replicate mobile devices, decrease the height until some part of the SideNav is not visible then try to scroll.

Note : My website have CoinHive installed.

I refered to the official Materialize SideNav documentation and it seems to me that I done a good job copying their Fixed HTML Structure code. I put the page through a HTML validator and there doesn't seem to be any problem. The only problem I can think of is that I messed up the coding somewhere.

The source code of the website is available [here](https://github.com/YiiKuoChong/YiiKuoChong/blob/master/templates/base/base.html)

Is there a particular reason why Materialize doesn't allow for the SideNav to be scrollable? or is it a bug?

Purpose of questions : I want to make a scrollable SideNav.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Seems like it's getting it's scroll back around ~615px height. Maybe that can give you a lead.

Comment: Yea I noticed that it is scrollable to a point but go no further though 615px wasnt it for me

Comment: I replaced dropdown `<ul>` first, the result is no change.

Comment: I replaced all `<ul>` found on page, the result is no change.

Answer (score 0):

Once you give an element `overflow-y: auto`, it's reacting to it's content. Therefore, it's not important what's the height of the div or the height of the screen, only if **the current client height of the div contains all the content**. You will only get the scroll when the bottom of the browser hits the bottom border of the content.

Now for a solution,

I would put the `<ul>` inside a `<div>` that gets the `overflow-y: auto`. Give that `<ul>` the min-height you want to start scrolling at.

Comment: Oddly enough, it does not work. I had the SideNav (`<ul>`) wrapped in a div and gave that div `overflow-y: auto` and a `min-height: 100vh`. The result is still the same, cannot scroll down.

Comment: Did you give the `<ul>` or the `<div>` min-height? I meant the `<ul>`

Comment: I gave the `<ul>` a min height, my bad.

Comment: Well, `100vh` is the height of the screen... try `800px`.

Comment: `200px` : Same like before but can't scroll down fully. `400px`: Same like `200px`. `800px`: Can't scroll at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `ul.sidenav.sidenav-fixed:hover { overflow-y: auto; }`

Comment: If you explain why this answer works you're likely to help more people with similar questions in the future :)